# ScrollView is not working inside the FrameLayout

Tags: android

The Below is my code i am not able to scroll the layout looking weird when i put `scrollview`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="willapp.stpl.com.willapp.util.ActivityPrintView">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">



    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table1heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select executer's relationship"
                android:id="@+id/txtHeading"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/mainactivity_layoutName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/table1heading"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainactivity_txtLabelName"
                android:text="Full Name:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </View>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainactivity_txtValueName"
                android:text="Sssdadaad"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mainactivity_layoutLine1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainactivity_layoutName"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainactivity_txtLabelLine1"
                android:text="Address Line1:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </View>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainactivity_txtValueLine1"
                android:text="Sssdadaad"/>

        </LinearLayout>





        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Would be helpful if Question is little more descriptive.

Comment: change RelativeLayout width to wrap_content and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ScrollView` try to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="willapp.stpl.com.willapp.util.ActivityPrintView">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       // and here your main Relative layout

       </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why cant relativelayout?

Comment: It worked, but the click listener is not working for the view which is inside the relative layout. Do you know how to fix this?